# Getting extra crisp border-radius elements

Tags: html, css, border, geometry

I'm getting these really crisp/pixelated circles and I don't really know what to do to stop it.

[image: CrispBorder]

Here's the code:

```
.flex-control-nav a {
 padding:3px; 
 border-radius:100%; 
 width:0px;
 height:0px;
 border:2px solid #fff; 
 float:left; 
 cursor: pointer; 
 text-indent: -999em;
 margin-left:5px;
}
```

Comment: What browser is the screenshot from? Post more of your code and a fiddle that recreates the problem.

Comment: Ahhh the old sub-pixel issue.

Comment: @SteveSanders I'm using Chrome. I'm using woothemes.com/flexslider and I'm not very familiar with fiddle so I can't make it work on there

Answer (score 0):

I'm not having any problems with that code, could it be your screen resolution?

You could try just changing the percentages, but keeping 100% should be just fine.

```
border-radius: 100px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8tsdLxny/
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TloHX.png

Comment: Well I doubt its a screen resolution problem because I went on your fiddle and it looks great. Tried 100px with no luck

Comment: Yeah I didn't think it would do anything.. I'm not sure. I'll keep looking around to see if I find anything.